# Meaning of return period on extreme events

Tags: time-series, extreme-value

If the distribution of the periods between an extreme event to another is a power law (as for example can be the return period of extreme earthquakes or flooding), the existence of the mean value is subordinated to the value of the exponent of the power law. In the cases where the exponent don't allow the existence of the mean or variance what is the meaning and the utility of the return period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of the time to return to an extreme state would be of interest whether or not it has a finite expected value.  In cases where the mean does not exist the median will still exist as a measure of central tendency and the median time to return would be a useful summary statistic for this distribution that tend to have long return times.

Comment: This question/answer could really benefit from an example